# Connection string Sybase

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sybase

Estou tentando conectar em um banco de dados SQL Anywhere 12 com o iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.dll, e estou com problemas para especificar a connection_string.

```
properties.Add("connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.SybaseSQLAnywhereDriver");
            properties.Add("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.SybaseSQLAnywhere10Dialect");
            properties.Add("proxyfactory.factory_class", "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle");
            properties.Add("hibernate.connection.provider", "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");
            properties.Add("hbm2ddl.keywords", "none");
            properties.Add("connection.connection_string", "Data Source=;UID=DBA;PWD=SQL;");
```

Mesmo informando o "Data Source" parece não conectar no banco que preciso conectar, e quando tento informar a propriedade "DBN", que acredito ser o nome do banco de dados, recebo este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: da uma procurada aqui: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Sim, me basei neste link para montar a string de conexão e parece estar certa, mas ele fica dando essa mensagem que precisa de permissão para iniciar e parar o bd e isso não posso fazer.